# Burning CD's with Brasero error

Tags: dvd, burning

(Sorry for my English)

So, my Windows Xp broke and I installed Ubuntu 13.04. I got back a Windows Xp iso and I'm considering dual-booting. The problem is that when I try to burn the iso, I get an error:

```
"SCSI error on write(640,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key B "Command aborted", ASC 00 ASCQ 00.".
```

The full error log is here:

http://pastebin.com/ue69cHqC

### Edit:

### Ok, so I installed K3B and bought a new DVD disk (still DVD-R). No problem with the burning. The problem probably was in Brasero. Thank you for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: I recommend [euDennis's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/383485/178596), but have you previously managed to write disks with your Ubuntu install? Your error log generally seems to consist of `Brasero`, so it is probably the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the best answer, but I never enjoy Brasero, usually it won't work. Install K3B (KDE CD Burner)  that work every time for me :)

Comment: +1 I was just typing the same answer at the same moment :-)

Comment: Afaik both k3b and brasero rely on the same software - cdrtools, or on it's broken debian fork - cdrkit. In general burning issues are solved by replacing `cdrkit` with `cdrtools`.

Answer (score 1):

> SCSI error on write(640,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key B "Command aborted", ASC 00 ASCQ 00.

This means that either the drive became impatient with
the medium, or Linux became impatient with the drive.
Brasero and libburn have few share in this problem,
except for the choice of write type.

> BraseroLibburn dvd/bd Profile= 11h , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 1

So this was a DVD-R medium.
There are two write types possible: DAO and Incremental.
Possibly the one fails and the other could work.
(Nevertheless, drive and media are on the edge of failure
then.)

I cannot tell from the log which one was chosen by Brasero.
If libburn was allowed to decide and Brasero told it the
size of the ISO image, then it was DAO.

---

If you want to try with other media: DVD+R and DVD+RW are
quite different from DVD-R and thus give best hope for other
results.

---

If you want to stay with DVD-R and want to try DAO versus
Incremental:

DAO (triggered by option -dao):

xorriso -as cdrecord -v -dao dev=/dev/sr0 SW_CD_Windows_XP_Professional_32BIT_English_ISO_MLF_X15-05160.ISO

Incremental (by -tao):

xorriso -as cdrecord -v -tao dev=/dev/sr0 SW_CD_Windows_XP_Professional_32BIT_English_ISO_MLF_X15-05160.ISO